# How to access custom view method from ViewPager2?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom constraint layout with a video that I want to be played

I created a custom `ConstraintLayout` class

```
class TvItemView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
): ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    var view: View

    init {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tv_item, this, false);
    }

    fun startVideo(){
        val videopath = "PATH_TO_VIDEO"+R.raw.takiya;
        val uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
        val vid = view.myVideo;
        vid.setVideoURI(uri)
        vid.start();
    }

    fun getMyView(): View {
        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm using this view inside a ViewPager2 to show the videos. The ViewPager2 is rendered in a fragment.

In my fragment, I'm trying to access this view and then start the video

```
tvViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback( object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                 
                    val myView = tvViewPager.findViewWithTag<TvItemView>(tvViewPager.currentItem);

                    myView.startVideo();

            }
```

However I am faced with this error

`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to com.company.app.TvItemView`

I don't see what is wrong because `TvItemView` is indeed a `ConstraintLayout` and I need it to be casted in the `tvViewPager.findViewWithTag<TvItemView>` for me to `startVideo();`

EDIT:

My PagerAdapter looks like this

```
class TvPagerAdapter(val items: List<Int>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TvPagerAdapter.ViewPagerViewHolder>(){

    inner class ViewPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
        val context = parent.context;
        val view =  TvItemView(context).getMyView();
        return ViewPagerViewHolder(view);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any `TvItemView` is indeed a `ConstraintLayout`; but it's saying you have a `ConstraintLayout` which is not a `TvItemView`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov But I'm indeed adding `TvItemView` to my PagerAdapter